# Instagram public API

Tags: salesforce, instagram, instagram-api, apex, instagram-graph-api

As we all know we can access Instagram posts raw content without logging in. Previously I have used **?__a=1** to get the content, later it's not worked. Then I used **?__a=1&__d=dis** I am getting post/reel content when loaded in my web browser, but its not giving me in the AWS its redirecting to login page. Then I decided to do it the Salesforce APEX. For the first time I got response like

```
{"graphql":{"shortcode_media":....
```

Afterwards(from 2nd time) I am getting response like below everytime even after waiting for some minutes.

```
{"message":"Please wait a few minutes before you try again.","require_login":true,"status":"fail"}
```

Is there any solution for this. Below is the APEX Code I am using

```
public class InstagramRequest {
    public static HttpResponse sendRequest() {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://www.instagram.com/p/CtHVCv9vdf4/?__a=1&__d=dis');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36');
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Are there any changes to the code to make it work.

Thanks.